# isync (mbsync) on gmail marks mail as new after move to another folder

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap, mutt, mbsync, isync

I'm trying to use (neo)mutt combined with isync (mbsync) for reading my mail from gmail account. However I have slight issue. When I use mutt to move mail to another folder, the message is marked as "new" again. Is there a way around this?

Relevant part of `~/.mbsyncrc` is I guess (rest is just mapping of remote to local folders and credentials)

```
# Automatically create missing mailboxes, both locally and on the server
Create Both
Expunge Both
# Save the synchronization state files in the relevant directory
SyncState *
```

I'm not sure what I should (can) do about this. Thanks for help